# UPDATE whole SQL Server Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a SQL Server table **Graph** with a column 'Probability' of data type *float*. This column contains values such as:

```
| Probability |          | Probability |
---------------          ---------------
| 0.052325243 |          | 0.05        |
| 0.155062365 |          | 0.15        |
| 0.347534343 |     =>   | 0.34        |
| 0.234532345 |          | 0.23        |
| ...         |          | ...         |  
| ...         |          | ...         |
| ...         |          | ...         |
```

I need to shorten the values in the same column as shown on the right side.

I tried the query as:

```
UPDATE Graph 
SET Probability = SELECT CAST(ROUND(ID, 2, 1) AS DECIMAL (18, 2))
```

where 'ID' is the primary key in the table. The error is incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Comment: Remove the 2nd `SELECT` so `SET Probability = CAST(...`

Comment: Also, be aware that float is approximate so you might get values like .1500000000000001 even with the round.

Comment: What @DanGuzman said.  If you need to explicitly control the decimal length of the data, then you should be using a data-type like `Decimal(p,s)` that supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Graph SET Probability = CAST(ROUND(Probability , 2, 1) AS DECIMAL (18, 2))
```

Hope this help!